# TYPO3 condition with session

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have this TypoSript:

Contance:

```
finish_day_value = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day
```

Setup:

```
plugin.Tx_Formhandler.settings.predef.formhandler-multistep-forms {
    if {
        1 {
            conditions.OR1 {
          AND1 = {$finish_day_value} > 7
          AND2 = {$finish_day_value} < 15
        }
         isTrue {
            markers.input_readonly_a_price = CONTENT
            markers.input_readonly_a_price {
              table = tx_pricelist_prices_full
              select {
                pidInList = {$get_carpid}
                orderBy = uid
                selectFields = uid, group_a_8_14
                # possible conditions
                 where = ( tx_pricelist_prices_full.uid='1' AND hidden='0' AND deleted='0')

              } 
              renderObj = COA
              renderObj {
                #value  
                1 = TEXT
                1.insertData = 1 
                1.data = field:group_a_8_14
                2 = TEXT
                2.value = *
                3 = TEXT
                3.insertData = 1 
                3.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day          
                stdWrap.prioriCalc = 1   
              }
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
```

The finish_day value is sending by the session from one form to another (that's why I use `TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day`). But when I insert it to Setup (for example):

```
AND1 = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day > 7 
AND2 = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day < 15
```

Nothings happens. So I try to define Constance value, but still nothing.

How to call the session value (finish_day) and use it on `AND` conditions?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is very specific. It depends on the extension you use.

If for AND1 is stdWrap implemented, you can use:

```
AND1.data = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day
AND1.intval = 1
AND1.noTrimWrap = | | > 7|
```

data: imports the data of the session
intval: we expect an integer, no chance for sql-injection here
noTrimWrap: i do not know, if you need the extra spaces.

Comment: I use Formhandler ext. Here is the example [link](http://www.typo3-formhandler.com/documentation/articles-howtos/a/how-to-set-up-a-multistep-form-with-conditions/)

Comment: Unfortunately - still nothing

Comment: so check what AND1 does support. Has it TypoScript support, or just custom support? You could try AND1 = {TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day} > 7

Comment: Conditions only allow a format like [fieldname]=[value], no special stuff. Is there a way that depending on the value of the field finish_day use TypoScript conditions? For Example: if TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day is greater than 7 use this TS and when less use that TS etc - like in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I used GlobalVar conditions:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day > 0] && [globalVar = TSFE:fe_user|sesData|finish_day < 4 ]
...
ts
...
[global]
```